# How to verify the Checksum values with downloaded files

Tags: eclipse, download, checksum, data-integrity, eclipse-indigo

Checksum values are given in the following link for downloading Eclipse IDE:

> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/R/eclipse-jee-indigo-win32.zip

I guess I can verify my download with the Checksum. Please anyone explain me how can I verify my download with the Checksum given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate a checksum of the downloaded file on your local machine and compare it to the checksum on the website.

If you are on a windows environment I suggest that you use [winMd5sum](http://www.nullriver.com/products/winmd5sum) to create the MD5 checksum on your local machine.

From a file explorer you can right-click on the downloaded file and "send to" winMd5Sum and then compare.

[image]

On linux I think most distros have a build-in `md5sum` batch command. You can use it like this:

```
md5sum <filename>
```

and compare result with the checksum on the website.

The calculation of MD5 checksums on large files can take some time.